# fxcop fails because of references on obfuscated assemblies

Tags: .net, assemblies, obfuscation, fxcop, gendarme

I need to run fxcop on a project that references an obfuscated commercial assembly (from dotnetremoting.com). Fxcop tries to load the obfuscated assembly and fails...
I have got exactly the same problem with Mono Gendarme. It also tries to analyse referenced assemblies and fails.
Thanks in advance for your responses

Alex

Comment: Not a real answer, but maybe, if you use very little of the types of the commercial assembly, you could create a dummy implementation. Then build your application in a special configuration where you link against those dummies. You can then at least use fxcop.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I had the same idea but it is not really the case, the lib is used all over the project I am affraid...

Comment: Have you attempted to contact the vendor of this commercial product for support?

Answer (score 0):

Gendarme has a test suite (unit tests and 'weird' binaries) that is used to ensure it does not fail* when loading assemblies. * at least not totally fail, if Cecil cannot load the assembly then it will be ignored.

You can contribute to both by submitting code - or tell where to find the binaries (if they are publicly available, e.g. a demo version).